# How to get recent Amazon Linux image in all regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ec2 describe-images \
--owners self amazon \
--filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" \
--query 'Images[*].[ImageId,CreationDate]' \
| sort -k2 -r \
| head -n1
```

I have written a script to get the latest Amazon Linux Image using AWS CLI. When I run this script, I get the latest Amazon Linux Image in my default region eu-west-1. How can I modify the code to get the latest image in all the regions.

Answer (score 1):

add `--region <region_name>` to your CLI command.

Something like this

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-west-2 \
--owners self amazon \
--filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" \
--query 'Images[*].[ImageId,CreationDate]' \
| sort -k2 -r \
| head -n1
```

Instead of hardcoding region names, you can use `aws ec2 describe-regions` command and get the list of regions and run your query for each region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html

Execute `aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].{Name:RegionName}" --output text` which gives output as

```
ap-south-1
eu-west-3
eu-west-2
eu-west-1
ap-northeast-3
ap-northeast-2
ap-northeast-1
sa-east-1
ca-central-1
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2
eu-central-1
us-east-1
us-east-2
us-west-1
us-west-2
```

Now loop thru each region and execute `describe-images` CLI command.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error when giving multiple regions For example: --region eu-west-1,us-east-1 "Invalid endpoint"

Comment: You cannot give multiple regions. You have to execute the command per region.

Comment: Thanks! I will give a try